# Annotate each object in MongoDB query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a Mongoose model with embedded documents:

```
const ticketSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  quantity: Number,
  price: Number,
  date: Date
});

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  tickets: [ticketSchema]
});

const Event = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

What I want is to extract all events with `Event.find({})`, but in each event, I want the date and price of the most recent ticket in the particular event, so I guess it's something like

```
Event.aggregate({ $groupBy: { $max: { tickets.date } });
```

Ii know this doesn't work, but I have to use some combination of `find`, `aggregate`, and `$max`.

Comment: You should look at `populate` mongoose method with `sort` and `limit` options: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: But in order to use populate, it seems I need to make tickets a separate model and use `{ type: ObjectId, ref: 'Ticket' }`.

Is it not possible with this data model?